# React Property types are incompatible. Can't get around Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tuples, react-big-calendar

I am in need of guidance on why this doesn't work and how it could be done better. I know the reason is because I am setting some of my properties inside my state as string whereas it is a type of Date in my object array.

```
const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = React.useState({title: "", start: "", end: ""});
```

```
const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = React.useState(events);
```

But the many tutorials I've seen is showing it works, they are using JavaScript whereas I am using typescript (don't know if there might be clashes because of the type dependency).

It gives an error when I try to add a new event into the `allEvents`

Seen beloew

````
const handleAddEvent = () => { setAllEvents([...allEvents, newEvent]) } ```
````

The error it gives is the following

```
const allEvents: {
        title: string;
        start: Date;
        end: Date;
    }[]
    Type '{ title: string; start: Date; end: Date; } | { title: string; start: string; end: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; start: Date; end: Date; }'.
      Type '{ title: string; start: string; end: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; start: Date; end: Date; }'.
        Types of property 'start' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'
```

The full code is as follows:

```
export interface IMeetingRoomBookingProps {
  description: string;
}

moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Paris')
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)


const events = [
  {
    title: "Store mødelokale",
    start: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 7, 30),
    end: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 8, 20),
  },
  {
    title: "Lille mødelokale",
    start: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 8, 30),
    end: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 10, 0),
  },
  {
    title: "Lille mødelokale",
    start: new Date(2022, 10, 4, 8, 30),
    end: new Date(2022, 10, 4, 11, 0),
  },
  {
    title: "Mødelokale Vest",
    start: new Date(2022, 10, 5, 7, 40),
    end: new Date(2022, 10, 5, 13, 15),
  },
]


const MeetingRoomBooking = ({ description }: IMeetingRoomBookingProps) => {

  const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = React.useState({ title: "", start: "", end: "" });
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = React.useState(events);


  const handleAddEvent = () => {
    setAllEvents([...allEvents, newEvent])
  }



  return (
    <div className={styles.parent}>
      <h1>Calendar</h1>
      <h2>Add New Event</h2>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setNewEvent({ ...newEvent, title: e.target.value })} placeholder='Add Title' style={{ width: "20%", marginRight: "10px" }} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.calendar}>
        <Calendar
          defaultView='week'
          localizer={localizer}
          events={allEvents}
          startAccessor="start"
          endAccessor="end"
          selectable
          style={{ height: 1050, width: 1050, margin: "50px" }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}



export default MeetingRoomBooking
```

EDIT SOLUTION if anyone ever has a stupid brainfart like me.

What I did was just instead of doing `const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = React.useState({ title: "", start: "", end: "" });` and setting the start, end type as an empty string.

I instead set them to new Date(), if that makes sense. Like this:
`const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = React.useState<IEvent>({ title: "", start: new Date(), end: new Date() });`

Comment: `start` and `end` are Date types. Either convert them to Date before updating state, or add `Date | string` type to `start` and `end` event fields

Comment: Could you elaborate ? I have updated my question so that it includes the whole code to give a clearer picture.

Comment: `React.useState({ title: "", start: "", end: "" });` uses strings instead of dates. Start by defining an interface instead of using anonymous types and then use `null` for the properties instead of empty dates